# Error inserting string at the beginning of a Linked List

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

I have been trying to write a program which inserts a string into the beginning of the linked list, however there has been a slight problem in it. My code is the following.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node{
    char* data;
    struct node* next;
};



void insIni(struct node** hp, char* x){
    struct node* tmp = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node)); 
    tmp->data = x;
    tmp->next = *hp;
    *hp = tmp;
}

void printList(struct node* h){
    struct node* tmp = h;
    printf("\nList contents: \n");
    while (tmp != NULL){
        printf("%s,  ", tmp->data );
        tmp = tmp->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]){

    struct node* head = NULL;  

     char word [256];
     scanf("%s", word);  
    insIni(&head, word);
    scanf("%s", word);  
    insIni(&head, word);
    scanf("%s", word);  
    insIni(&head, word);

    printList(head);

    return 0;
}
```

After I insert a new string at the beginning of the linked list, the previous elements are also changed to be the same as the string that has just been insterted, how can I change my code so that the previous elements of the linked list stay the same and only the element at the beginning is added?

For example, if I write A B C, the Linked List ends up being printed as C, C, C, instead of C, B, A,.

Comment: It works, but `scanf("%s", word);`  in main() reads the input into the same character array each time. you could replace `tmp->data = x;` in isnsIni() to `tmp->data = strdup(x);`

Comment: Ok, that change seemd to solve my problem, however when compiling I recieve the following warning:  incompatible implicit declaration of built in function 'strdup'.

Is this dangerous? And if so how can I remove it?

Comment: You need to `#include <string.h>` to use strdup() (NOTE: strdup is *slightly* non-standard)

Comment: strdup is POSIX and that is very well a standard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value you pass to insIni is always the same so all nodes will point to the same. What you need to do is a copy of the data.

E.g.

```
void insIni(struct node** hp, char* x){
    struct node* tmp = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node)); 
    tmp->data = strdup(x);
    tmp->next = *hp;
    *hp = tmp;
}
```

or

```
char *p = malloc(strlen(x)+1);
strcpy(p, x);
tmp->data = p;
```

Comment: The solution with strdup seems to work, thanks!
However, when compiling, I receive a warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built in function 'strdup'. Is this dangerous? And if so, how can I remove it?

Comment: @GeorgeFrancis you need to include the appropriate header. any function which the C compiler finds that has no prototype is assumed returning int. `#include <string.h>`

Answer (score 0):

`scanf` reads the text into the array `word`. In the call `insIni(&head, word);`, you do NOT pass the string but the address of the array `word`. In `insIni` in the line `tmp->data = x;` you copy that address to the element data. But it's still the array `word` from function `main`. So next `scanf` will overwrite the content of that array. The next call to `insIni(&head, word);` will then assign the same address to the next struct. So, what you actually need is to allocate memory for the string, either prior (or after) the `scanf` statement or in `insIni`. Something like `char * word;` instead of `char word [256];` and `word = malloc(256);` in front of every `scanf` will do the job. Also, `scanf` is dangerous because of buffer overflows, so you probably want to read this one:
[How to prevent scanf causing a buffer overflow in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1621394/how-to-prevent-scanf-causing-a-buffer-overflow-in-c)